# Plus/Minus jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Não estou conseguindo mudar o valor do input **id="value"** quando clica em **.minus** ou **.plus**, o que devo fazer para resolver?

```
<input type="button" value="+" class="plus">                                                

<input  id="value" step="1" max="99" min="1" title="Qty" class="qty" type="number" name="prod[<?php echo $result['id']?>]" value="<?php echo $result['quantity']?>" size="4" />

<input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
```

jquery

```
$('.plus').click(function() { changeValue(1); });
$('.minus').click(function() { changeValue(-1); });

function changeValue(val) {
    var container = $('#value');
    var current = parseInt(container.html(), 10);

    container.html(Math.max(0, current + val).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque `container.html()` para `container.val()`. O `.html()` serve para pegar o HTML interno do elemento e não o valor. O `.val()` sim irá pegar o valor do `input`.

```js
$('.plus').click(function() { changeValue(1); });
$('.minus').click(function() { changeValue(-1); });

function changeValue(val) {
    var container = $('#value');
    var current = parseInt(container.val(), 10);
    container.val(Math.max(0, current + val).toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="+" class="plus">                                                

<input  id="value" step="1" max="99" min="1" title="Qty" class="qty" type="number" name="nome" value="3" size="4">

<input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
```